# Securing an API for specific clients with user authentification

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a RESTful API and I want that just a specific trusted desktop client can access the API on behalf of a user. Sure thing, OAuth is the way to go, as most people say. But I have a few problems trying to understand why and how I should use OAuth.

First, I don't want my server to store passwords, so I decided to use other OAuth/OpenID providers for logging in. Also just my desktop client is allowed to interact with the API. So the server needs to check if:

- The request is coming from this particular client
- The request is coming from a valid user

That said the user shouldn't see a "Allow this application to interact on behalf of you"-Screen when signing in and I don't need any scopes.

I've read that two-legged OAuth1.0a is the one I should choose, but then they say that OAuth1.0a is deprecated and you should consider using OAuth2 for new integrations. I already implemented a method similar to Amazon AWS, but then I have noticed that I just can authenticate a client, not a user, with this method.

**So, what's the way to go for my needs?**
*I'm sure something like this has already been asked before, somewhere, somehow, but this is so confusing and frustrating.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0), four flows are defined. Among them, "[Client Credentials Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)" does not require user interaction. In the flow, a client application can be issued an access token only by presenting its client credentials (= client ID and client secret).

It seems what you should do are:

1. To implement the [token endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) for the client credentials flow. In the implementation, the client ID and the client secret should be checked and an access token should be issued.
2. To implement the API (this is called *"protected resource endpoint"* in OAuth 2.0). In the implementation, you should check whether the access token presented by the client application is associated with the expected client application. The API should return a valid response only when the client application is the expected one. [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) (Bearer Token Usage) lists three ways how an access token is presented at the token endpoint.

Comment: Thanks! I ended doing this exact thing a few days ago. Works perfect.